# Mac Zip without "surrounding Folder" on PC?

Tags: mac, windows, zip

I have a problem with Mac Zip files in exchange with Windows PC.
My Mac folder structure looks like that:

Folder

- File 1
- File 2

If I create a Zip from "Folder" on a Mac and copy that to the PC and extract it there, the structure looks like this:

Folder

- Folder

  - File 1
  - File 2

Is it possible to create a Zip on a Mac without having the surrounding Folder on my PC?

Comment: I think this *may* be  Windows thing. If you create a zip archive on Windows (Select items to zip, right click and "send to > Compressed zip folder") you get a zip archive that acts like a folder. If you then right click on this zip archive and "extract to..." you get a dialog asking where to extract to, with the default being the location of the zip file  + a folder named the same as the zip file. You may need to use something other than Windows Explorer to unzip stuff (WinRAR, etc...) as I don't think your issue is related to the Mac.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a ZIP by using the Compress option in Finder on "Folder" you get a ZIP structured like this:

```
$ unzip -v test.zip 
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Stored        0   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  test/
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  test/a
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  test/c
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  test/b
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       0                6   0%                            4 files
```

So if you get an additional folder when unpacking on Windows this rather seems to be a problem with the unzipper there.

You can work around this on macOS by going *into* the folder, select all the files there and select "Compress" from the context menu. This will create a ZIP file without a parent folder:

```
$ unzip -v Archive.zip 
Archive:  Archive.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  a
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  b
       0  Defl:N        2   0% 02-21-2022 14:07 00000000  c
--------          -------  ---                            -------
       0                6   0%                            3 files
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer nohillside! But since I have a lot of folders to compress, I hoped there is a way to do that without selecting the files themself. I already played around with Mac Automator, but my programming knowledge ist just too basic to achive proper results.

Comment: @alf Maybe best to ask a new question then, describing your specific problem, giving some details about the size of the task, and indicating that you need to have scripting/automation solution.

Comment: I totally agree, next time I'll write a better description.

Comment: @Alf No worries, a lot of problems need several rounds to get to the bottom of it and find good solutions.